# Connect WordPress container with MySQL container

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker

I'm trying to build a new application with WordPress using Docker containers but I failed to connect it with MySQL container. 
 
 I use this command to build MySQL container . 
`docker run --name wordpress-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress -d mysql:latest`

 and this for run wordpress container . 
`docker run --name wordpress-blog --link wordpress-mysql:mysql -p 8083:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=wordpress-mysql:3366 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress -e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_ -d wordpress`

**Now** wordpress container doesn't run and return this error . 
`Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
2018-07-02T07:49:49.727093500Z 
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused`

Comment: Did you solve the error?

Comment: Unfortunately, No @javalisson